# C# Console application not working properly on Windows Server (works fine on win XP and win 7)

Tags: c#, windows

I am having huge problem with application I made for `windows server 2008 R2.`

The application works on `.NET framework 3.5`, and as far as I know windows server 2008 R2 contains such a framework.

Application itself is pretty massive, it is a server program for registering employees work time, by barcode scanner, then store it in .`xml` file, it also does update itself from `update.xml` file every few minutes.

To avoid having this application in focus all the time i used some methods to capture keypressed without focus on application.

So to the base of my problem, application is launching properly, it is also reading codes properly and identifying them, but application is apparently having problem with "break:" and "return", and it simply does not launch one of my methods inside of my program. (it is simple static void method without any arguments)

Do I have to rewrite whole program to make it work without calling methods and all breaks and returns? Or what is the problem. This is quite important for me, deadline is more or less today. I could also add that this application is working perfectly fine on other pc's, and when I'm debugging it on my pc, it also works as intended.

I won't post whole code here, it is simply too massive, but I can post parts of it to help you guys.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

    static void Main()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
        appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        if (AutoStarter.IsAutoStartEnabled == false)
        {
            AutoStarter.SetAutoStart();
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(appPath+"\\Raporty"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "\\Raporty");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(appPath+"\\settings.jsn"))
        {
        utworzsetting();
        }
        sprawdzostatniawersje();
        uaktualnij();
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
     }





    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);





    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            switch (vkCode)
                {
                   case 48:
                     wiersz = "";
                     break;
                   case 49:
                     wiersz += "1";
                     break;
                   case 50:
                     wiersz += "2";
                     break;
                   case 51:
                     wiersz += "3";
                     break;
                   case 52:
                     wiersz += "4";
                     break;
                   case 53:
                     wiersz += "5";
                     break;
                   case 54:
                     wiersz += "6";
                     break;
                   case 55:
                     wiersz += "7";
                     break;
                   case 56:
                     wiersz += "8";
                     break;
                   case 57:
                     wiersz += "9";
                     break;
                   case 13:
                     if (wiersz != null)
```

a few "If"'s

And finally

```
                             if (aktualneID != -1) // Jezeli ID znajduje sie bazie danych
                         {
                             // MySettings settings = MySettings.Load(appPath + "\\settings.jsn");
                             if (settings.limit == true && lPracownik[aktualneID].Dni.Count != 0)
                             {
                                 czymoze();
                                 if (niemoze == false)
                                 {
                                     Console.WriteLine("z limitem");
                                     asdf();
                                     Console.WriteLine("nie wywolalem metody");
                                 }
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 Console.WriteLine("bez limitu");
                                 asdf();
                                 Console.WriteLine("nie wywolalem metody");
                             }
                         }
                     }
                            wiersz = "";
                            zapiszbaze();
                     break;
                   default:
                     break;
```

This is where is the problem, application goes to this moment `"Console.WriteLine("bez limitu");"` and that's it, it doesn't launch "`asdf`" method, it also doesn't go for  wiersz = "";

I would appreciate any help, if you have any more questions, wants me to specify some things just tell.

PS. I am using `VS 2010 Express`, if you think that you can help me, I could send you entire solution.

Comment: You've posted a lot of code, can you please explain what asdf does? Sure its not just throwing an error? if it did, it would explain why the call may not seem to be happening and certainly why wiersz="" isnt happening.

Comment: asdf just determines if worker started his work or stopped for today, it is void fuction. It does not return any value. Ive putted "console write line" in first line of asdf() and program doesn't even go there. Also sorry for naming it "asdf", it was named differently but i was trying to figure out why its no working, even tried to change name of method. Sigh

Comment: Then its crashing with an error.. put some try loops round things, with error messages to console etc.

Comment: I just guess it could be problem with .NET framework, it might be different on Windows Server 2008R2, but why the program starts then? If it couln't find the library it should not start at all, and insteed it is just maulfuncioning.

Comment: The program shows Console.WriteLine("bez limitu");
After that it goes back to cases. And i can put new charater in

Comment: There maybe other reasons why it errors.. Hence, put some error trapping in!

Comment: Atm i am updating .NET framework on windows server 2008R2, hopefully .NET 3.5.1 will fix the problem, becasue i simply cannot see any other reason why application wouln't run properly just on this single machine.

Comment: Viola, problem solved. Altho i have one more problem to deal with. I need to make this app work after reboot, but without loggin on any account. Atm it is in registry autostart, but it requrie you to log on account. I want to make it work like service, to work without loggin in.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it was .NET framework malfunction, I have reinstalled it on server and everything works like a charm.